# Select * query for sequences does not show all columns in output. (PG 11.5)

Tags: sequence, postgresql-11

I am upgrading postgres from 9.1 to 11.5 .

but select query on sequences is returning different output in 11.5 as compared to 9.1, not all columns are shown in the output.

**Output in 11.5**

```
SELECT *  FROM session_SEQ;
```

11.5:

```
last_value | log_cnt | is_called
------------+---------+-----------
          1 |       0 | f
(1 row)
```

Output in 9.1:

```
SELECT *  FROM session_SEQ;

sequence_name | last_value | start_value | increment_by | max_value | min_value | cache_value | log_cnt | is_cycled | is_called
---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------
session_seq   |          1 |           1 |            1 |  99999999 |         1 |           1 |       0 | f         | f
```

How can we display all the columns in 11.5? is there any workaround?*

Answer (score 1):

You can query the pg_sequences and pg_class table to find this information out, like:

```
select relname,pg_sequence.* from pg_sequence inner join pg_class on pg_class.oid=pg_sequence.seqrelid;
```